# Azure B2C Support for Single user with multiple concurrent credentials

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My users are being stored in Azure AD B2C.  I want my users to be able to login using more than one credential (Example local and Google).
Does AzureB2C support allowing more than one credential for the same user ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. User object in AD has a `signInNames` property which can have multiple credentials. For example

```
"signInNames": [
                {
                    "type": "emailAddress",
                    "value": "someuser@somewhere.com"
                }
            ]
```

You can either use Graph API or Azure Portal to edit credentials.

For more information on Graph API and specifically SignInName property see https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#signinname-type

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C can manage a user object that combines a local account (with one or more sign-in names) with one or more social accounts.

[The Wingtip sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c) contains an example of an interactive flow that links the user object for a local account with a social account.

See [the "B2C_1A_link" relying party file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_link.xml) and [the "Link" user journey](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/89b0c2e3f78605521e16d443a160fdbb0e5acca9/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L3596) for reference.

Note this user journey prompts the end user to log in with a local account before they log in with the social account.

You can also [create the user object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-social-migration#migrate-social-account-with-local-account) using the Azure AD Graph API:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "creationType": "LocalAccount",
    "displayName": "David Hor",
    "givenName": "David",
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "Test1234",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "signInNames": [
        {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "david@examplecom"
        }
    ],
    "surname": "Hor",
    "userIdentities": [
        {
            "issuer": "google.com",
            "issuerUserId": "ZGF2aWRAY29udG9zby5jb20="
        }
    ]
}
```